# Filtering a list of names from query

Tags: sql, coldfusion, qoq

I have a query something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM qAll 
WHERE name not in('Alina,Charaidew,Sukapha')
```

which is not working. What will be the best way to do so? As this list a generated dynamically and maybe different every time.

Comment: [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause)

Comment: why `ColdFusion`? is `qAll` a `query` object?

Comment: For ColdFusion; simply use [quotedValueList()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6d16.html) like `WHERE name not in (#quotedValueList(tempNameList)#)` where tempNameList is a variable that has comma separated name values.

Comment: @user3733648 - It sounds like your question is about QoQ's, not sql server, which is a totally different animal. Modified tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CF, You should use cfqueryparam to for your query parameteres. To pass a list as parameter, you should add list attribute to the cfqueryparam.
Your query should be similar to below:

```
<cfset nameList = "Alina,Charaidew,Sukapha">
<cfquery name="queryName" datasource="#Application.ds#">
        SELECT * FROM qAll WHERE name NOT IN (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" list="Yes" value="#nameList#" >)    
</cfquery>
```

Comment: You still need the parentheses around the list, I think?

Answer (score 4):

Sql server treating `'Alina,Charaidew,Sukapha'` as a single Value, that's why are not getting any result.

Query should be like..

```
SELECT * 
FROM qAll 
WHERE name not in('Alina','Charaidew','Sukapha')
```

Answer (score 2):

> Considering `qAll` is a query object.

`'Alina,Charaidew,Sukapha'` is representing a single value so, you need to specify that it is a list by using [`cfqueryparam`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfqueryparam.html)'s list `attribute` like:

```
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="someName">
    SELECT * 
    FROM qAll 
    WHERE name NOT IN (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="Alina,Charaidew,Sukapha" list="yes" separator=",">)
</cfquery>
```

*Note:- This is case sensitive.*

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts here:

1. The root of the issue is the way your list is formed. SQL is looking for a comma separated list with single quotes (') as the text qualifier. The entire string is contained within single quotes (') and therefore treated as a list of one.

Yours:

```
SELECT * 
FROM qAll 
WHERE name not in('Alina,Charaidew,Sukapha')
```

Correct SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM qAll 
WHERE name not in('Alina','Charaidew','Sukapha')
```

2. In ColdFusion, it is preferable to use the cfqueryparam tag when using the cfquery tag. This helps with performance and in the event your list is a variable, guards ( somewhat ) from sql injection. Please note the 'list="Yes"' attribute. This will qualify your list appropriately with single quotes as the text qualifier at runtime.

```html
    <cfset names = "Alina,Charaidew,Sukapha">
    <cfquery name="queryName" datasource="#Application.ds#">
            SELECT * FROM qAll WHERE name NOT IN (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" list="Yes" value="#nameList#" >)    
    </cfquery>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use dynamic qyery also..

```
declare @filter nvarchar(50)
,@sql nvarchar(4000)
set @filter ='Alina,Charaidew,Sukapha'

set @sql ='SELECT * 
FROM qAll 
WHERE name not in('''+replace(@filter,',',''',''')+''')';

exec (@sql)
```

Comment: Best to avoid dynamic sql unless it is really needed (in this case it is not) because it poses a sql injection risk.  Though it sounds like they are using a QoQ rather than an actual database query anyway.